# History back navigation using ng-include

Tags: android, cordova, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I started to develop a single page web app with angularjs and now I'm defining the navigation.  So, I end up using 2 levels of navigation:

1st level: Main navigation using ng-view.

2nd level: SubView navigation with the top and bottom bars using ng-include.

This is our iphone scenario:

[image: App Scenario]

The iphone scenario seems ok for me because we control all navigation with our buttons.
But, now lets think in android scenario where the user can use the history back button(physical button) to navigate back. How can we support it if we use ng-include for the subnavigation?

[image: workflow using history back]

Thanks in advance

Comment: You know that every Android device has a back button / key? (On most devices this is a real physical hardware button.)

Comment: @TheHippo This is what I'm asking! How to support this button... if the user is navigating in the main.html and press the button back(the physical one), it will go back to the SignIn.html sreen and not to the previous subview, I guess.

Comment: The Android back button behaves like the browser history back button, as long as you are in web context. So if you support some kind of url history you do not need to take any more actions.

Comment: What I think @MarcCanalsGiraut is trying to say is since the Main.html only changes the content of the subview, the web context does not track the real history of the context.

Comment: Yes! I updated the question adding more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a parameter to your URL to make it work with Android history.

```
#/main?page=1
#/main?page=2
```

Then use **that** to control the state of your app, and then android back button will work.

You can set url parameters with `$location.search`:

```
$location.search('page', 4);
```

$location.search docs: [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$location#search](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24location#search)

And one more thing: You'll want to add `reloadOnSearch: false` option to your `$routeProvider.when()` declaration for your view.  By default, the whole view reloads when you change a query parameter with `$location.search()`.  Setting that to false will make it not reload, which is what you want in this case:

```
$routeProvider.when('/main', { reloadOnSearch: false });
```

reloadOnSearch docs: [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$routeProvider#when](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24routeProvider#when)

Comment: mmmm I haven't thought about it. I would say this is a posible solution, so I will try it! Thanks @Andy Joslin!